# A better way to map a function that requires IO over a list

Tags: haskell

So lately I have a list of strings, and need to independently go over each one and perform some `IO` function.

So basically what I have is this:

```
goOverList :: [String] -> IO ()
goOverList (x:[]) = do
    putStrLn x
goOverList (x:xs) = do
    goOverList [x]
    goOverList xs

main = do
    let myList = ["first", "second", "third"]
    goOverList myList
```

My `IO` is a bit more complicated but that is the gist of it (needing to have a function go over a list and do `IO` based on the list member) I was hoping someone might show me how to do this better.

Answer (score 15):

Your `goOverList` function is almost equivalent to `mapM_ putStrLn`. (Just almost because `mapM_` also works with the empty list while your function does not).

[`mapM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell98/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:mapM) is a function that applies a function of type `a -> IO b`¹ to each item in a list of `a`s and gives you back an `IO`² with a list of `b`s. `mapM_` is the same as `mapM` except that it doesn't store the results in a list (which doesn't make sense for actions that return `()` like `putStrLn` does).

¹ Actually it's more general than that: The function has type `a -> m b` where `Monad m`, but in this case `m` is `IO`.

² Again it's actually m.

Answer (score 9):

sepp2k and solrize are right to recommend `mapM_`.  But, in the spirit of teaching you to fish instead of giving you a fish, here's something you can try in the future:

1. Try to come up with the type signature of the operation that you need.  For example, in your case, you want something of type `(String -> IO ()) -> [String] -> IO ()`.
2. Go to the [Hoogle search engine for Haskell libraries](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and search for that type.
3. That one has no results, so try modifying the type a bit to make it more generic.  Replace `String` with `a` to get `(a -> IO ()) -> [a] -> IO ()`, and search for that.

Now the third result of [the second search](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+IO+%28%29%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+IO+%28%29) is `mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`, which is exactly what you want.  (The first answer, `closeFdWith :: (Fd -> IO ()) -> Fd -> IO ()` is not a relevant result; the second, `traverse_ :: (Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f ()` is relevant but a bit more complicated to understand and use.)

Answer (score 4):

First, easy improvement:

```
goOverList' :: [String] -> IO ()
goOverList' []     = return ()
goOverList' (x:xs) = do
    putStrLn x
    goOverList' xs
```

The base case for recursion should be the empty list: in that case, you simply return the IO action `return ()` which does nothing. When you have one or more elements, you print  it and continue with the rest of the list, simple as that.

The same exact thing is achievable in a way more compact definition with `mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`: it is the same as the regular `map`, except that it works with monadic actions. Instead of returning the collection of results `m [b]` like the regular `mapM` would do, it throws it away. It works just fine for you in this case, as you're are only interested in printing out the elements of he list.

```
goOverList'' :: [String] -> IO ()
goOverList'' = mapM_ putStrLn
```

In order to be even more general, we could rely on `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()` instead of `putStrLn` and accept in input every list of "showable" items:

```
goOverList''' :: (Show a) => [a] -> IO ()
goOverList''' = mapM_ print

data T = One | Two | Three deriving (Show)

main = do
    let myList = [One, Two, Three]
    goOverList''' myList
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `goOverList` function can be written `mapM_ putStrLn` where `mapM_` is a function in the standard Prelude.

You can also simplify your own implementation:

```
goOverList :: [String] -> IO ()

goOverList [] = return ()

goOverList (x:xs) = do
    putStrLn x
    goOverList xs
```