# Haskell print map over array

Tags: haskell, printing, dictionary

I'm practicing with a problem that gives text input on stdin and wants output on stdout.
They give an integer T in the first line that I read, and then T lines follow. For the T following lines I have a function that takes an integer and returns an integer that I must print. So my output should be T lines.
I'm stuck at this point:

```
main = do
    strcases <- getLine
    map (calculate) [1..(read strcases)]

calculate _ = do
    strp <- getLine
    print $ addone (read strp)

addone x = x+1
```

Of course this doesn't work at the moment. Can you show how to print the T lines of output?

Comment: You want `mapM_`.  It's the monadic map function

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403993/a-better-way-to-map-a-function-that-requires-io-over-a-list) for an elaboration.

Comment: BTW, you can simply write `mapM_ calculate [1 .. read strcases]`: no need for any parentheses there! And `print $ read strp + 1` would work, too. However I would in both cases advice against `read`, better use `readLn` to directly get the correct type. (Both `read` and `readLn` are somewhat unsafe, they don't really handle parse failure in a nice way... but I suppose that's not really an issue for your application.)

Comment: Also, since you discard the parameter to `calculate`, you can use `replicateM_ (read strcases) calculate` instead of `mapM_ calculate [1..(read strcases)]`, and eliminate the `calculate` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `readLn`, which combines `getLine` and `read`, and `replicateM_` from `Control.Monad` to repeat an `IO` action (or any monad) a given number of times:

```
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- readLn
    replicateM_ n calculate

calculate :: IO ()
calculate = do
    x <- readLn
    print $ addone x

addone :: Int -> Int
addone x = x+1
```

Note, the underscore suffix on `replicateM_` indicates that the return value of each executed action be discarded.  The alternative function without the underscore suffix will return a list containing the return value of each executed action, which we do not want in this case.